# When must one consider the order of independent probabilities?

Tags: probability

So the simple question in my book was: each player from a three player team kicks a ball and tries to make a goal. the probabilities for them are 65%. 75% and 54%.
What is the probability that at least one makes a goal.

Now I calculated it and got the right answer: $1-(0.35*0.25*0.46)=0.95975$

However, this got me thinking, why don't we consider the order between the players? For example player A could kick before player B and vice versa. So it would be $1-(0.35*0.25*0.46)-(0.25*0.35*0.46)-....$

I just can't wrap my head around it. Why don't we consider the different order they could kick?

Comment: Well, regardless of the order the product is the same.  And regardless of the probabilities one assigns to each order, they sum to $1$.

Comment: Notice also that if the probabilities of missing were each $0.99$ then the solution you offered would be well below $0$.

Comment: alright I gave a good bit of thought to my question, and I came to the conclusion that it comes down to the fact that the order is not important. We can calculate the probability for A kicks, then B, then C. Because the probability is going to be the same independent who kicks first, and it's going to be one of those orders, aka the same probability. That is you can calculate these independent probabilities as if first a,then b etc... But we can't consider the different orders in the same probability, because "it's one or the other, not both". Maybe I'm wrong, feel free to correct me.